# Expression for infinite product

Tags: co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, generating-functions, elliptic-functions

can anyone show me  how

$$\displaystyle\frac{4}{R}\displaystyle\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+R^{-4n}}{1+R^{-4n+2}}\right)^4=  \frac{1}{R}\left(1+2 \sum_{n=1}^ {\infty} \frac{1}{R^{2n(n+1)}}\right)^2\left(1+2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{R^{2n^{2}}}\right)^{-2}  $$

The above identity is obtained by Komatu [page no, 58] (Y. Komatu, "A coefficient problem for function univalent in an annulus", Kodai math. Rep., 8, 1956, 49-70.)

Jacobi's triple product identity is
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x ^{n^{2}}y^{2n} = \prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-x^{2m})(1+x^{2m-1}y^2)(1+x^{2m-1}y^{-2})   $$

substitute   $ x = \frac{1}{R^2}$ , $y= \frac{1}{R}$

$$ 1+ 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ R^{2n(n+1)}}  = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1- R^{-4m})(1+R^{-4m})(1+R^{-4m+4})   $$ 
how $ \;\;\;
(1+R^{-4m})(1+R^{-4m+4}) = (1+R^{-4m})^2  $

If Jacobi's triple product identity is
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x ^{n^{2}}y^n = \prod_{m=1}^\infty (1-x^{2m})(1+x^{2m}y)(1+x^{2m}y^{-1})   $$

substitute   $ x = \frac{1}{R^2}$ , $y= \frac{1}{R^2}$

$$ 1+ 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ R^{2n(n+1)}}  = \prod_{m=1}^\infty (1- R^{-4m})(1+R^{-4m-2})(1+R^{-4m+2})   $$

for second equation, subs $ x= \frac{1}{R^2}, y= 1   $

$$ 1+ 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{ R^{2n^{2}}}  = \prod_{m=1}^\infty (1- R^{-4m})(1+R^{-4m})^2   $$

Comment: For the first substitution, pay attention to what happens at $n=0$ and $n=-1$.

Comment: Try writing out the infinite product by hand and keep track of each term. It will be obvious how to regroup them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the original identity has an exponent of $4$ on the left hand side that you have missed. Moreover it is not correct as stated, by simply comparing constant terms of both sides. However it is just a simple typo probably, because the following is true
$$\frac{4}{R}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+R^{-4n}}{1+R^{-4n+2}}\right)^4=  \frac{1}{R}\left(2+2 \sum_{n=1}^ {\infty} \frac{1}{R^{2n(n+1)}}\right)^2\left(1+2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{R^{2n^{2}}}\right)^{-2}.$$
To prove it you just have to use some specializations of [Jacobi's triple product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product). Indeed it says
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n^2}y^n=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-x^{2m})(1+x^{2m}y)(1+x^{2m}y^{-1})$$
substituting $x=\frac{1}{R^2}$ and $y=\frac{1}{R^2}$ gives
$$2+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{R^{2n(n+1)}}=2\prod_{m=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{R^{4m}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{R^{4m}}\right)^2$$
and substituting $x=\frac{1}{R^2}$ and $y=1$ gives
$$1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{R^{2n^2}}=\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{R^{4m}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{R^{4m-2}}\right)^2.$$
Komatu's identity follows by dividing the first equation by the second and squaring.

Comment: first equation is obtained, from jacobi's triple product , we have $ 1 +2\sum_{n=1}^{\infinity} \frac{1}{R^2n(n+1)} = \pi ( 1- \frac{1}{R^{4n+4})(1+ \frac{1}{R^{(4n-2)(n+1)/n})^2

Comment: I added the details.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer pointed out, with the typo fixed, the equation is
$$\frac{4}{R}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+R^{-4n}}{1+R^{-4n+2}}\right)^4=  \frac{1}{R}\left(2+2 \sum_{n=1}^ {\infty} \frac{1}{R^{2n(n+1)}}\right)^2\left(1+2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{R^{2n^{2}}}\right)^{-2}.$$
After replacing $R$ with $q^{-1/2}$ we get
$$4q^{1/2}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1+q^{2n}}{1+q^{2n-1}}\right)^4 = 4q^{1/2}\left(1+ \sum_{n=1}^ {\infty} q^{n(n+1)}\right)^2 \Big{/} \left(1+2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}q^{n^{2} }\right)^2.$$
The left side is $k(q)$ and the right side is $\theta_2(0,q)^2/\theta_3(0,q)^2$ which is a standard equation. See, for instance, [DLMF equation 20.9.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.9#E1) and [Abramowitz and Stegun equations 16.38.5 and 16.38.7](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_579.htm).